# Gitlab: Cloning (via ssh) on a fresh install fails with “The remote end hung up unexpectedly”

Tags: gitlab

Pushing to a new repo in a fresh gitlab installation (6.0.1) fails with

```
Access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But ssh -vT git@www.my.gitlab.eu works.

Answer (score 8):

When

> sudo -u git -H /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check

I got:

```
Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 503

Check directories and files: 
    /home/git/repositories: OK
    /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
```

In the gitlab-shell.log I found a html response which said:

> ERROR
>
> The requested URL could not be retrieved
>
> The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL:
>   http://my.gitlab.eu//api/v3/internal/check
>
> Unable to determine IP address from host name my.gitlab.eu
>
> The DNS server returned:
>
> Name Error: The domain name does not exist. This means that the cache
>   was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. Check if
>   the address is correct.
>
> Your cache administrator is admin@example.com.

I edited the config file of gitlab-shell

```
/home/git/gitlab-shell# sudo -u git -H editor config.yml
```

like this

```
# Url to gitlab instance. Used for api calls. Should end with a slash.
#gitlab_url: "http://my.gitlab.eu/"
gitlab_url: "http://123.xxx.xxx.xx"
```

The end slash leads obviosly to a double slash in the api call despite the hint in the comment. In my case the dns could not be solved. So now I use the ip address and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off selinux.

```
setenforce 0
```

Also set SELINUX to permissive in /etc/selinux/config.

Then go upvote this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24212432/162070

Comment: Why the downvote without a comment? I've had the exact issue and this solved it. Might not help the OP, might help somebody else. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check your account permisions. Only owner can commit in master branch. If your account is of type Developer you need to create new branch and member who is owner will merge your branch with master branch.