# GitLab SSH requests password and ignoring SSH Keys

Tags: linux, git, ssh, centos, gitlab

I have a fresh gitlab-omnibus installation on a CentOS 6 box, I have configured it correctly and can access the web interface, I've added my SSH key however when I try to Git Clone a newly setup repo, I am asked for a password for the Git user via SSH. I have tried this with three different machines and three different accounts, and still the issue persists.

Here is the output from a verbose SSH

```
╭─jacobclark@Jacobs-MacBook-Pro  ~  
╰─$ ssh -vT git@gitlab                                                                                                                                                                     130 ↵
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab [37.26.93.221] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/jacobclark/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/jacobclark/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jacobclark/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jacobclark/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA a1:62:aa:51:0c:20:f3:3e:10:17:c7:20:a4:0b:7b:16
debug1: Host 'gitlab.' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/jacobclark/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/jacobclark/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/jacobclark/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@gitlab's password:
```

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/17740432/6309 help? Or https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3384? or http://serverfault.com/a/555021/783?

Comment: What does the server's auth/etc. log say when you try to connect? What are the permissions on the .ssh directory (and files in it) for that user on the server?

Comment: Did you add your SSH key via the GitLab webinterface? Or did you add it to the authorized_keys unix style?

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn off selinux:  `setenforce 0`

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue on CentOs, turned out to be due to Centrify being used to manage ssh keys, which is non standard, but part of our corporate server management processes.

I'm not overly familiar with Centrify as its managed by another team, but I resolved this issue by creating a sym link from the gitlab authorised-keys file into /etc/sshd/auth-keys/git.

The authorizedkeys file value gave me the location the sym link needed to go to, determined  with `sshd -T`

Resulting in this resolving my issue:

```
ln -s /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys /etc/ssh/auth-keys/git
```